# What do you lose when you enter prestige mode in MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When you prestige in Modern Warfare 3, do you lose access to your weapon level unlocks (such as the proficiencies, reticle changes, etc.)?

Is there a comprehensive list of what you lose and what you keep when you enter prestige mode?

Comment: weapon level is kept through out the course of the game and when you prestige all you must do is be a high enough level to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially you lose everything.  It's like starting over again from level 1.

This time around you can pay Prestige Tokens to get early unlocks, (ie, the AK-47 or Steady Aim at level 1) but the weapon/perk/gear's status is reset and you will have to level it as you normally would on each Prestige.  For instance, if you had gold camo on a gun and all the attachments, even if you use a prestige token to "Unlock Gear," you'll lose the attachments/camo and you'll have to level the weapon again.

The only thing that is saved from one prestige to the next is any Titles and Emblems you've received from doing challenges.  The challenges themselves reset, however.  If you're really close to the end of a challenge that unlocks a title or emblem, it might make sense to finish it before using your Prestige.

You also get to keep the quantity of custom classes, although your custom classes reset to the defaults when you Prestige.  You'll also not have access to custom classes until you reach the level where they unlock on the first pass.

Answer (score 6):

Given that one of the things you can buy with prestige tokens is "Unlock Gear", which allows you take something with you through to your next prestige, I suspect you do lose weapon proficiencies.

Comment: I'm confused. The fact that you can purchased the right to keep your gear probably means that you generally *will* lose access to it. Right?

Comment: When you say "buy", you mean with real money or fake money ( I mean points earned during the game...)

Comment: @LucM When Mechko said "buy" he specifically mentions the prestige tokens (fake money). When I said "purchased" I meant the same.

Answer (score 4):

Your gun levels reset you can as stated above buy gear but you will have to level it up again but it does mean you can have a good gun you like when you prestige the unlock gear as far as i know is just for the Gun itself not any of the attachments or proficiencies they havnt to be earned back.

The unlock Gear token allows you to either buy a gun, a perk, a side arm or a tactical (Claymore ect) but you can only get one so takes several prestiges to buy a whole class (Have recently prestiged and tested this) but you still need to get to level 4 to use custom class if you do unlock gear.

Answer (score -4):

You lose everything and start back at level 1.  Your weapon rank starts all over and you dont have all the guns.